# C: typedef union

Tags: c, typedef, microcontroller, unions, microchip

didn't find anything in related questions. Most probably it's super noob, but I'll ask anyway/ I've got the following in my .h file:

```
typedef union _API_Packet_0x90{
    uint8_t packet[26];
    struct _pack_struct {
        uint8_t start;
        uint8_t length[2];
        uint8_t addr64[8];
        uint8_t addr16[2];
        uint8_t options;
        uint8_t rfData[4];
        uint8_t chksum;
    };
} API_Packet_0x90;

API_Packet_0x90 ap90;
```

This is code for a microcontroller, I'm using xc8 toolchain (former Hi Tech C). The compiler says:

> xbee_api.h:19: warning: missing basic type; int assumed
>     xbee_api.h:19:
>   error: ";" expected
>   xbee_api.h:19: warning: missing basic type; int  assumed
>   xbee_api.h:21: warning: missing basic type; int assumed

, and this goes on (too many errors)

I thought it's uint8_t, so I added `#include <ctypes.h>`. Nope. I thought it is about names, so I tried all kinds of plays such as

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t packet[26];
    struct _pack_struct {

    };
} API_Packet_0x90;
```

or

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t packet[];
    struct _pack_struct {

    };
} API_Packet_0x90;
```

or others. Nothing helps. I'm stuck as I believe I'm following syntax properly. Any help?

Comment: How do you know the include you added defined uint8_t ? Maybe try to add 'typedef unsigned char uint8_t;' before that definition... either it will help or it will complain you are redefining it.

Comment: You probably need `#include <stdint.h>` for `uint8_t`.

Comment: `xbee_api.h:19:` can you also give line numbers of your code? at least the number of first line? So that we can know, which line is giving problem.

Comment: If `_pack_struct` is an abbreviation of "packet structure", I would advise against it lest it is confused with "packed structure" which is a different thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uint8_t` is located in `stdint.h`, not in `ctype.h` (nor ctypes.h, no such header exists). You must use a compiler that follows a newer version of the C standard for this header to be found (C99 or C11 standards).

Comment: I thought it was a super-stupid mistake. That was it. Thank you.

Comment: Or add a define of your own for the unknown data type.  There is no requirement to use a compiler that follows a newer version of the C standard.  Or search and replace the data type with another the compiler knows.  You have choices.

Comment: @dwelch Of course you can define the type yourself, I haven't said anything to contradict that. But to find the header stdint.h you must use a newer compiler, as written in my post.