# Is it legal to alias a char array through a pointer to int?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

I know that the following is explicitly allowed in the standard:

```
int n = 0;
char *ptr = (char *) &n;
cout << *ptr;
```

What about this?

```
alignas(int) char storage[sizeof(int)];
int *ptr = (int *) &storage[0];
*ptr = 0;
cout << *ptr;
```

Essentially, I'm asking if the aliasing rules allow for a sequence of chars to be accessed through a pointer to another type. I'd like references to the portions of the standard that indicate one way or another if possible.

Some parts of the standard have left me conflicted; (3.10.10) seems to indicate it would be undefined behavior on the assumption that the dynamic type of `storage` is not `int`. However, the definition of dynamic type is unclear to me, and the existence of `std::aligned_storage` would lead me to believe that this *is* possible.

Comment: Can the people downvoting leave comments please?

Comment: I don't know if you can do this, but it is defined by the standard to access a variable in a [`aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) in the way you are trying to

Comment: I didn't vote, but if asking for references to standard, I would expect you to show your own research and cite portions that you think are relevant - and describe your own conclusions that you are unsure about.

Comment: @chbaker0 Looking at the link I gave above it looks like the a sample implementation (hopefully standard conforming) does almost the same thing you are doing here

Comment: @user2079303 good point, I'll add in my research that left me conflicted

Comment: @DarthRubik Thanks, I noted the extistence of that in my edit

Comment: "Dynamic type" is useful for classes, not scalar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code `int *ptr = (int *) &storage[0]; *ptr = 0;` causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule (C++14 [basic.lval]/10)

The objects being accessed have type `char` but the glvalue used for the access has type `int`.

The "dynamic type of the object" for a `char` is still `char`. (The [dynamic type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) only differs from the static type in the case of a derived class). C++ does not have any equivalent of C's "effective type" either, which allows typed objects to be "created" by using the assignment operator into malloc'd space.

---

Regarding correct use of `std::aligned_storage`, you're supposed to then use placement-new to create an object in the storage. The use of placement-new is considered to end the lifetime of the `char` (or whatever) objects, and create a new object (of dynamic storage duration) of the specified type, re-using the same storage.  Then there will be no strict aliasing violation.

You could do the same thing with the char array, e.g.:

```
alignas(int) char storage[sizeof(int)];
int *ptr = new(storage) int;
*ptr = 0;
cout << *ptr;
```

Note that no pseudo-destructor call or `delete` is required for built-in type `int`. You would need to do that if using a class type with non-trivial initialization. [Link to further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466556/aligned-storage-and-strict-aliasing)

Comment: The second part got to the core of my misunderstanding; I didn't realize that the object type was established through use of placement `new`.

Comment: So this would mean that using `malloc` then using resulting memory as an `int` or any other primitive other than `char` is also undefined unless you do placement new?

Comment: @chbaker0 yeah it is not very well known; omitting the placement-new and doing strict aliasing violations appears to work most (or all) of the time so many people just do that either unaware of the problem, or not concerned with the Standard.

Comment: According to the standard - that's correct, you must use placement-new on malloc'd space before writing into it.

Comment: Re the "end the lifetime" part - see P0137R1 for some tweaks (and a special case for arrays of unsigned chars)

Comment: @T.C. yes, hopefully this can all be improved so that common constructs like we are discussing is actually made to be well-defined

Comment: "_The objects being accessed have type char_" No. You made that up. The code is fine.

Comment: @curiousguy `char storage[sizeof(int)];` creates an array of `char` objects.

Comment: @M.M And also every POD object that fits in this region of memory!

Comment: @curiousguy The standard does not support your claim . Really, it is preposterous to say that declaring a char array makes effectively an infinite number of objects. This thread is about what the standard actually says, not what you wish it says.

Comment: @M.M Please explain what is problematic with an infinity of objects at the same address, beside you not liking the idea.

Comment: 1) Why pass the address of `storage` as a `char*` (`storage/&storage[0]`) instead of a `char (*)[sizeof(int)]` (`&storage`) to the `new` operator? I assume it doesn't matter and is simply easier to write, or are there other nuances involved? 2) Since the lifetime of `storage` ended after placement new, accessing it would lead to UB, correct?

Comment: @303 the argument is converted to `void *`

Comment: Sorry for asking such a silly question... :/

Answer (score -1):

The `union` construct might be useful here.

`union` is similar to `struct`, except that all of the elements of a `union` occupy the *same* area of storage.

They are, in other words, "different ways to view the same thing," just like FORTRAN's `EQUIVALENCE` declaration.  Thus, for instance:

```
union {
  int   foo;
  float bar;
  char  bletch[8];
}
```

offers three entirely-different ways to consider the *same* area of storage. (The storage-size of a `union` is the size of its longest component.) `foo`, `bar`, and `bletch` are all synonyms for the *same* storage.

`union` is often used with `typedef`, as illustrated in this StackOverflow article: [C: typedef union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197998/c-typedef-union).

Comment: The question has the C++ tag and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning this is not legal in C++ (but it is in C).

Comment: And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521188/type-punning-a-struct-in-c-and-c-via-a-union says the same thing.

Comment: C++ does not allow type punning via unions . You can only read out of the most recently assigned-to member.

Comment: Oh, foo ... how right you are ... me bad.  **:*(**  ... (*"type punning"* ... somehow I hadn't heard this term before. But, I like it.)

Comment: @M.M "_You can only read out of the most recently assigned-to member_" That isn't true either.

Answer (score -3):

```
*ptr = 0;
```

writes to an int, so it is an access to int, with an lvalue of type int, so that part of the code is fine.

The cast is morally fine, but the C/C++ standard texts don't clearly describe casts, or pointers, or anything fundamental.

Comment: They do clearly describe it, you just seem to disagree with the implications of what the standard says so you pretend it doesn't say that.

Comment: @M.M "_They do clearly describe it_" I am please to learn that. Please see and answer my many questions regarding pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32100245/963864

Comment: @M.M The implication here that any use of union was undefined until recently is beyond silly.